# docker-compose: Service 'web' failed to build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to install `apach2, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and openssl` in the container. I've removed some packages and fix typos in `Dockerfile` but the error is still there.

When i run `docker-compose build` my setup is running ok, until it hit the part in the `Dockerfile` where I'm initializing this install and I've got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package RUN
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package install
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     apache2     libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3     curl     dpgk-sig RUN apt-get install -yq openssh-server' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

You can check the whole installation process [here](https://pastebin.com/skDzrWYz), and this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN cat /etc/passwd
RUN cat /etc/group

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
RUN apt-get install -y openssl
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code

EXPOSE 80

ADD config/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache/sites-available/000-default.conf
ADD config/start.sh /tmp/start.sh
ADD src /var/www

RUN chown -R root:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx /var/www
RUN find /var/www -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx {} +
RUN find /var/www -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} +

#essentially: CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
CMD ["/tmp/start.sh"]
```

Can someone explain me why is this happening, and how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
```

The `\` is a continuation and the next thing it sees is `RUN` so is treating that like a package (which it can't find). Lose the `\` and it should work fine.

Comment: Ops, missed that, need to turn on the lights, tanks.